# How to avoid "compiler limit: compiler stack overflow" with large vector inits?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my unit tests I get the following compiler error:

```
 The error message indicates as follows: 
 'fatal error C1063: compiler limit: compiler stack overflow'
```

This is caused by some generated headers which contain:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> GetTestData()
{
     return { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 }; // Very large 500kb of data
}
```

How can I use vectors in this way without crashing MSVC? Note that the code builds OK in clang and gcc.

Comment: 500k of integer literal?

Comment: Why are you not doing the sane thing by adding the data to the vector within the function, and thus just return the vector?

Comment: I guess it should not be in the code anyway. can't you serialize the data to outer file and deseriealize it on run time in chunks? I think it's the best approach..

Comment: I added it to the code to avoid doing file I/O it just have hard coded sample data in unit tests only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting your data into a const static array and then use vector's range ctor:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> GetTestData()
{
    static const unsigned char data[] = { 
        0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0x0,
             ...
    }; // Very large 500kb of data

    return std::vector<unsigned char>(data, data + sizeof(data));
}
```

EDIT: Thanks Lundin for pointing out about const.

Comment: your answer wins over Marks because without the static keyword it takes 1 hour to compile!

Comment: An option might be to generate the data at runtime rather than hardcode each entry

Comment: @paulm  If this is a Windows program, that proper way to do this is to place the data in your program's resources and populate the vector from those resources.  Look up `RCDATA` and its uses.

Comment: Should actually be `static const` as `.rodata` is less likely to overflow than `.data`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the program is multiplatform so I couldn't use the resources

Comment: @paulm leaving out the `static` keyword was a simple oversight. I prefer `std::begin` and `std::end` when available over the pointer arithmetic employed here, as it documents your intent and reduces the chance of an error.

Comment: @Mark I agree about std:begin and std::end

Comment: In the end I did use std::begin/end - but static is what actually allowed it to build

Answer (score 1):

Try building a large array for initialization, rather than using an initializer directly.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> GetTestData()
{
     static const unsigned char init[] = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 }; // Very large 500kb of data
     return std::vector<unsigned char>(std::begin(init), std::end(init));
}
```

Comment: This could easily overflow the runtime stack, couldn't it?

Comment: Indeed. Not making it `static const` will merely move the stack overflow from the compiler to the application...

Answer (score -1):

Even if it builds fine in clang and gcc I wouldn't recommend returning large vectors like this by value.  If the data you are working on is immutable  i would return it as a const reference like:

```
// EDIT Moved vector outside of function
static const std::vector<unsigned char> static_v({ 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 });
    const std::vector<unsigned char> & GetTestData()
    {
    return static_v;
    }
```

Comment: Anything wrong with relying on move operations? They've been official for 4 years now.

Comment: @Angew Absolutely nothing. But returning a static const reference at least guarantees that the time consuming vector<...> constructor only gets called once. If you need a mutable vector<...> you may later invoke `vector<...> vv = GetTestData()`which generates a (time consuming) temporal copy and invokes the move semantic for you.

Comment: For some reason this way of doing it still crashes the compiler

Comment: @Oncaphillis Fair enough.

Comment: @paulm That's because the work for the parser & compiler is basically the same in this case.

Comment: @Angew copy elision handles the case of returning by value (aka. NRVO), that has been in since C++98

Comment: Why do you want to move static vector outside of function? I do not think it is a good solution to enforce function to return a reference to guarantee constructor called once, this approach has another issues. If it is really necessary it probably should return smart pointer, at least intention would be clear for function caller.

Comment: @MattMcNabb But it's true that if the function's return value is used in a read-only way with multiple calls, the reference to `static` would be more efficient. Nevertheless, the whole thing is unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Slava My assumption was that MSVC really tries ti generate code that places the temporal array {0x01,0x02...} on the stack as a local variable. I admit it doesn't win a prize of elegance and readability.